# Ionic 2 Native plugins does not work on device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I'am using some Cordova plugins in my Ionic 2 application (camera, Geolocation, Facebook), but when i try to use them i have a message : "Native: tried calling Camera.getPicture, but the Camera plugin is not installed." but all my plugins are installed.

Any Suggestions ?

**EDIT**

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.7.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.7.0

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3
Node              : v6.10.3
OS                : Windows 10
npm               : 3.10.10
```

Comment: Can you show the part of the code that throw the error

Comment: its no really a error, i have an icon to take photo with camera.getPicture, when i click i have the message "Native: tried calling Camera.getPicture, but the Camera plugin is not installed." but all my plugins are installed". same thing for faceboo.

Comment: Are you using npm packager to install the module lib?

Comment: yes i do, i test it with the social sharing native plugin, and same thing i have this message : "Native: tried calling SocialSharing.canShareViaEmail, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator " in Chrome remote debugger.

Comment: @digit Olso if it can helps, i have "Provisional headers are shown" in some of my requests, Google Maps olso does't work and i cant get local images !

Comment: Are you running this on browser or real device? you must run in a real device in order to get it work , otherwise the same error will be thrown because ionic does not compile native library in a browser.

Comment: I'm running on Real device.

Comment: @NacimIdjakirene , same error , any updates?